# Использование PostgreSQL вместо SQLite при развертывании JupyterHub

Tags: linux, postgresql, jupyter-notebook

Разворачиваю JupyterHub на Debian Stretch, поднял реверс прокси через Nginx, добавил сертификаты осталось вынести базу из SQLite, что идет по умолчанию, на уже готовую PostgreSQL, доступной на отдельном хосте.

Описание этого процесса плохо задокументированно да и в конфигурации `/etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py` нет явного указания на базу: обычно в конфигурации есть описания типа базы, хост или IP, пользователь, имя базы и порт подключения, чего в указанном файле нет.

Если кто то разворачивал JupyterHub в связке c PostgreSQL, разъясните, где именно это указывается в настройках.

Единственное, что нашел в документации - это ввскользь упомянутая PostgreSQL, которую желательно использовать в продакшене: https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/database.html?highlight=Database

Answer (score 0):

JupyterHub использует https://www.sqlalchemy.org/ для работы с базами данных, подключение происходит после указания всех деталей в ключе `c.JupyterHub.db_url`, что не сразу ясно из документации.

Пример использования с функцией `format`

*/etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py*

```
...
c.JupyterHub.db_url = 'postgres://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format("user","password","host","port","db")
...
```

После указания деталей базы, нужно перезапустить сервис. На стороне базы нужно создать пользователя **user** и базу **db**, пользователь должен иметь полные права на чтение и модификацию базы. Схема создается автоматически  и не требует дальнейших манипуляций.